# Accessing nested Javascript JSON properties through Variables

Tags: javascript, json, variables, properties, nested

Say I have a config file in which I have paths to JSON properties. My JSON looks like:

```
var test = { test: { test2: { test3: 1 } } }
```

and I have a string `str = "test.test2.test3"`

I know I can access the top level one like this: `var foo = "test", test[foo]`

But `test["test.test2.test3"]` does not work. On the other hand `test["test"]["test2"]["test3"]` works, but this is not a one liner if I have more complex objects (some can be 5 levels in, some can be 3 etc)

Is there any way to access this property directly instead of splitting on the dot and looping through?

Comment: That isn't JSON, it is a JavaScript object literal. JSON is a data format based on a subset of JavaScript (which that code does not conform to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with(test) eval(str);
```

Did anyone's head explode?

It's either that or

```
eval('test.' + str);
```

Take your pick from the bad practice basket.

Though for the first example if you actually want the value you'd want to do this

```
var value;
with(test) value = eval(str);
```

But that kind of takes away from the purity of this bad practice masterpiece.

Comment: Ah thanks, eval completely slipped my mind, for those very reasons. I haven't seen with yet, so that's interesting.